# Finding the lone occurence of a value in a table

Tags: mysql, sql

Lets say I have the following tables.

```
TABLE L
id      name
51      joe  
52      sara
53      john
54      david

TABLE M
id      l_id
1       51 
2       51
3       52 
4       53
```

In table M, there are rows with multiple values for the information in table L. What I am trying to do is select a count of everything which appears just once in table m.

So in the above case, the count would be 2 because they are the l.id's that appear only once in table m:

```
COUNT(*)
2
```

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: Count not 3 must be ? 51 52 53 ?

Comment: Count would be 2 because 52 and 53 are the l.id's that appear just once in table M. l_id 51 appears twice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select Count(*)
from
  (select l_id From M group by l_id having count(*)=1) m
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use a count(*) on a sub query which returns just the rows having a count of =1.  My mysql is a little bit rusty but I hope the following code will give you an idea.

select count(*) from (
 select l_id, count(*) count from m
group by l_id
having count(*) = 1
)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT count(*)
FROM table
HAVING count(id) = 1;
```